# Set print layout as default view in Word 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2013

Every time I open a document downloaded from the Internet in Word 2013, the document is displayed in protected view and in Read mode.

I want the Print layout to be the default instead. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried already? There's ways to do it in previous versions.  Have you tried those yet?  Specifically  File -> Options -> General tab- > Un-check "Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view".  Are you saving the files to disk first, or trying to open them directly form the Internet?

Comment: thanks, this is what I am looking for. You can make it to an official answer and I will accept it

Comment: @techie007: You should mark put this in its own answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to keep Protected View enabled but still disable Reading View as default, go to **File** > **Options** > **General** > Uncheck **Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view**.

This is safer than disabling Protected View altogether.

(Thanks to folks in the comments for pointing out the above.)

---

You can go further and turn off Protected View for downloaded files by going to

**File** > **Options** > **Trust Center** > **Trust Center Settings...** > **Protected View** > Uncheck **Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet**. You may want to uncheck the other two boxes while you're there.

(This applies in Word 2010 as well.)

After that, editable files will open normally and in Print Layout. No need to also turn off Reading View specifically if you go this route, at least in Word 2013 Preview.

Keep in mind that this will do away with the [protection](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU&fromAR=1) from malicious scripting that may be hidden in untrusted documents you've downloaded. If you're worried about that, you should probably just disable opening in Reading View as described in the first part above and leave Protected View enabled.

Comment: So there's no way to have a document protected (i.e. not editable) but in print view?

Comment: oh... apparently there is, it's just in the comment, not in its own answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 9):

Something to try:

Check out File -> Options -> General tab- > Un-check "Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view".